# Как правильно настроить кодировку ввода БД?

Tags: база-данных, кодировка, php

**В файле httpd.conf Apache**

```
     #
     # Denwer: default charset.
     #
     AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

**Сервер баз данных**

Сервер: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP

Программа: MySQL

Версия программы: 5.5.25 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Версия протокола: 10

Пользователь: root@localhost

Кодировка сервера: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

**У БД, всех таблиц и полей сравнение utf8 unicode ci**

**В коде php**

```
     header("content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

и

```
     mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
```

**В html**

```
     <meta charset='utf-8'>
```

В результате:
[Скрин1](http://joxi.ru/gmvjRbpSd46Lma), [Скрин2](http://joxi.ru/823gOzdCaRNQ2O)

Как исправить?

Comment: @tanias08, скиньте, пожалуйста, неверно декодированную строку текстом. Есть одна идея откуда начать раскручивать.

Comment: если я правильно вас поняла:

name Грымза Алена Петровна
pass 123456
specialization manager
user manager2
Исходный код
user=manager2&pass=123456&name=%D0%93%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B7%D0%B0+%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0&specialization=manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@tanias08](/users/16286/tanias08)](/users/16286/tanias08), "%D0%93%D1..." - это url-кодированная строка, тут всё нормально. А вот на первом скрине, где вы показываете данные в таблице, проблемка присутствует и возникает она у вас на этапе внесения данных в базу. И как вы обрабатываете данные перед запросом, было бы гораздо интересней узнать.

P.S. Я не удивлюсь, что причиной ваших бед может быть и Denwer, т.к. проект мёртв уже несколько лет, не обновляется и не поддерживается. Да и сама сборка очень сомнительного качества.

Comment: Блиииин. Называется "забудьте все, что читали в книгах". Проблема действительно была в обработке данных перед запросом, взяла функцию "призванную обезопасить ввод данных" из американской книжки, конечно, у них то там проблем с кодировкой нет...
Спасибо большое, @Deonis!!!

Comment: @tanias08, не за что. В MySQLi есть такое понятие, как [подготавливаемые запросы][1], которые отвечают за экранирование данных.

   [1]:http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Answer (score 3):

**1 способ**: Если есть права на изменение `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, то попробуйте добавить в него следующее:

```
character_set_server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**2 способ**: Попробуйте наследоваться от нативного класса mysqli, прописав в конструкторе следующее:

```
class Db extends mysqli
{
  public function __construct($host = 'localhost', $user, $password, $dbname)
  {
     parent::__construct($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
     $this->set_charset('utf8');
  }
}

$db = new Db('localhost', 'tom', 'pass', 'db_name');
```

Comment: не, не помогло :(

Comment: @tanias08 Если применили 1-ый способ, то после внесения изменений в конфиг требуется рестартонуть mysql: `sudo service mysql restart`. По конфигу взгляните ещё [сюда](http://softtime.ru/forum/read.php?id_forum=3&id_theme=73048)

Comment: Возможно, нужно еще добавить в секцию [mysqld] (туда же нужно добавить и вышеуказанные настройки):

skip-character-set-client-handshake

Мне когда-то помогло.

Comment: Не, тоже не помогло :(

Comment: А если еще добавить:

    collation-server=utf8_general_ci
    init-connect="SET NAMES utf8"

?